# Outer Galois representations and Tate modules of Jacobian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, galois-representations, profinite-groups, fundamental-group

Let $X$ be a proper smooth curve over a field $k$. Then we have an exact sequence of profinite groups
\begin{equation*}
    1 \to \pi_1(X_{\overline k}) \to \pi_1(X) \to G_k \to 1, 
\end{equation*}
which induces an outer Galois representation
\begin{equation*}
    G_k \to \mathop{\mathrm{Out}}\left(\pi_1(X_{\overline k})\right). 
\end{equation*}
Show that after abelianization, we have an isomorphism of $G_k$-modules
\begin{equation*}
    \pi_1(X_{\overline k})^\mathrm{ab} \cong \prod_\ell T_\ell(J_X), 
\end{equation*}
where $J_X$ denotes the Jacobian variety of $X$ and the $G_k$-module structure on $\pi_1(X_{\overline k})^\mathrm{ab}$ is induced by the outer Galois representation.

Comment: Have you tried looking in Szamuely's book "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups"? That's usually a good place to look for things like this.